# Openshift internal server error when loading page

Tags: javascript, php, server, openshift

I recently deployed my web page to Openshift. Everything works fine expect when I try to load a particular script(which is not in any way special).

I use this script to load page content:

```
function AjaxLoadJQuery(pageToLoad){
        var requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        requestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (requestObject.readyState == 4 && requestObject.status == 200)
            {
                document.open();
                document.write(requestObject.responseText);
                document.close();
            }
            if (requestObject.readyState == 4 && requestObject.status == 404)
            {
                alert('belaj');
            }
        };
        requestObject.open("GET", pageToLoad, true);
        requestObject.send();
    }
```

I pass it the path of the page I wish to load. The page in question is a contact form name kontakt.php, which is located in the same folder as index.php.
All the other pages are also in this folder and for them there is no problem, but when I try to load this page I get this error:

GET http://webtehnologijegranulo-wtgranulo.rhcloud.com/servis/Struktura/kontakt.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is my web app(not in english). The link not working is the second on the right("KONTAKT"):

http://webtehnologijegranulo-wtgranulo.rhcloud.com/servis/Struktura/index.php

What could be the cause?

Comment: Yes and all the other pages have the same path /servis/Struktura/PAGE.php

Comment: I have figured it out... it was an error in php(typo).